# Как через JS удалить div, который блокирует ссылки в футере?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, html5

Есть сайт:
https://evroflag.by/
Через пару секунд пояляется див, который блокирует контент.
Как его удалить с помощью JS?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Извлекаешь родителя этого div, извлекаешь сам div. А потом parent.removeChild(childDiv)

Comment: Как это прописать в моём случае?